# Why the latest filelist could not be output via the remote ssh ls -l ？

Tags: shell, ssh

Environments: SuSE 15 SP1
Problem:      It is so strange that some latest filelist could not be output via the remote ssh ls -l .

```
jchadb2:/scripts # 
jchadb2:/scripts # 
jchadb2:/scripts # ls -ltr /scripts/*.sh
-rwxr-xr-- 1 root root 1519 Dec 23  2019 /scripts/hacfg_trans_v2.sh
-rwxr-xr-- 1 root root 1519 Dec 23  2019 /scripts/hacfg_trans.sh
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 1550 Dec 31  2019 /scripts/hafile_trans_dos.sh
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 1516 Dec 31  2019 /scripts/hafile_trans_ux.sh
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 1497 Dec 31  2019 /scripts/hafile_trans.sh
-rwxr-xr-- 1 root root 1523 Dec 30 18:34 /scripts/habak_trans_v2.sh
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 1548 Dec 31 10:57 /scripts/hafile_trans_v2.sh
-rwxr-xr-- 1 root root 1622 Dec 31 16:30 /scripts/habak_trans_v3a.sh
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 1647 Dec 31 17:18 /scripts/hafile_trans_v3a.sh
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 1647 Dec 31 17:18 /scripts/hafile_trans_v3.sh
jchadb2:/scripts # 
jchadb2:/scripts # 



jchadb1:/scripts # 
jchadb1:/scripts # 
jchadb1:/scripts # ssh jchadb2 ls -l /scripts/*.sh
-rwxr-xr-- 1 root root 1476 Dec 11  2019 /scripts/habak_trans.sh
-rwxr-xr-- 1 root root 1519 Dec 23  2019 /scripts/hacfg_trans.sh
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 1550 Dec 31  2019 /scripts/hafile_trans_dos.sh
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 1516 Dec 31  2019 /scripts/hafile_trans_ux.sh
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 1497 Dec 31  2019 /scripts/hafile_trans.sh
jchadb1:/scripts # 
jchadb1:/scripts #
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have files on `jchab1:/scripts` that match `/scripts/*`

so

```
ssh jchadb2 ls -l /scripts/*.sh
```

first, expand localy to

```
ssh jchadb2 ls -l /scripts/habak_trans.sh .. (no _v2 files)
```

next, `ls -l /scripts/habak_trans.sh ..` is sent to `jchab2` (and still no _v2. file)

and on remote hosts, only explicit file are listed.

compare

```
ssh jchadb2 ls -l /scripts/*.sh
```

and

```
ssh jchadb2 ls -l /scripts/*_v*.sh
```

try escaping *

```
ssh jchadb2 ls -l /scripts/\*.sh
```

Comment: Great ！   It  really need \\* <br/>

Comment: But how to understand that the wildcard "*" with remote ssh ls -l  cannot expand/mismatch the "_v" ....？

Comment: I update my answer, be aware that command line is expanded localy before command part in ssh is sent to remote host.

Comment: My doubt is why the same "*"  just cannot expand/mismatch the "_v"  ？

Comment: because there is `_v2` files on jcab1

Comment: But why other "_[alphabet]" on jchab1 can be expand/match，  such as "_ux"、"_dos" ？